# How to see the code of a stored plot (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to know whether it is possible to see the code of a plot that is stored in a variable. For example, given the following plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

myData <- data.frame(x=1:100, y = 100:1)
myPlot <- ggplot(myData, aes(x,y)) + geom_line()
```

I'd like to have a function "seeCode" that returns the actual code used to construct the plot:

```
>seeCode(myPlot)
  ggplot(myData, aes(x,y)) + geom_line()
```

Comment: @MrFlick that's an answer. Convert!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That information isn't retained. There's not a one-to-one mapping from ggplot object to the code that produced it, just as there's no way to know if a "5" came from "3+2" or "4+1".

Comment: I thought ggplot_build(myPlot) returns how the plot was created.

Comment: It translates the `ggplot` object into something that can be plotted. There certainly is information about how the object might have been created, but there is no inverse function that exists. And you can arbitrarily modify the `ggplot` object however you like (it's just a list) so it might not translate nicely to simple ggplot function calls.

Comment: I did not know about ggplot_build(). Although it does not return the statement that constructed the plot it makes it easy to retrieve some useful info. Thanks @lawyeR