# Is there any way to convert a gTree back to a workable ggplot in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-grid

Here is some example data:

```
exampledata <- structure(list(x = c(2.93131952459005, 3.21275054434318, 1.36466997175509, 
2.13626543532502, 1.45889556823722, 1.94598707699052, 0.719062322132357, 
2.38139571953234, 2.37813367615963, 3.98126576880209), y = c(7.51581380181603, 
9.77495763943671, 8.9666894018554, 8.62675858853528, 7.89238665417542, 
9.84865061237773, 7.24526820962333, 7.64727218939944, 7.28026738945878, 
8.6913070524479), z = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), z2 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("cat", "dog"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

The plot of that data:

```
asdf <- ggplot(exampledata, aes(x = x, y = y, color = z, shape = z)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line(aes(color = z, linetype = z2))+
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(1,2,3)) +
  theme(legend.position = 'top', 
  legend.spacing = unit(2, 'cm'))
```

This code below just increases the size of points within the z component of the legend (independently of the lines in z or actual points in the figure). The output of this is a gTree object. Although this section might seem arbitrary, it is an important step for the final plots

```
grid::grid.ls(grid::grid.force())

# Set the size of the point in the legend to 2 mm
grid::grid.gedit("key-1-[-0-9]+-1.2-[-0-9]+-2-[-0-9]+", size = unit(4, "mm"))

# save the modified plot to an object
g2 <- grid::grid.grab()
ggsave(g2, filename = 'g2.tiff')
```

Now imagine a scatter plot of the following dataframe:

```
datasetb <- structure(list(x = c(2.55279478309192, 0.929375129220925, 1.56509894419863, 
2.48026699500513, 1.18018131012236, 1.79675395182943, 0.817046700547386, 
1.99710482619256, 2.18780091987683, 3.41661353718804), y = c(8.88460717718884, 
9.11053089978428, 7.68492406933585, 8.23110925234432, 7.48154953916593, 
9.0253526297593, 9.41899905471655, 8.54779428609509, 9.17050925351926, 
5.83078691211861)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L
))

b <- ggplot(data = datasetb, aes(x = x, y = y) +
  geom_point()
```

I want to be able to use `plot_grid` to combine these plots into one. However I don't think a gTree can be used as an argument to `get_legend`. Is there any way to convert a gTree back into a ggplot object, or any workaround

Below is my end goal.

```
prow <- plot_grid( asdf + theme(legend.position="none"),
                   b + theme(legend.position="none"),
                   align = 'vh',
                   labels = c("A", "B"),
                   hjust = -1,
                   nrow = 1
)

legend_a <- get_legend(asdf + theme(legend.position="top"))


p <- plot_grid( legend_a, prow, ncol = 1, rel_heights = c(.2, 1))

tiff("BothPlots.tiff", units = 'in', width = 12, height = 7, res = 400)

p
dev.off()
```

Comment: not sure if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41940000/modifying-ggplot-objects-after-creation

Comment: @user63230 Hmm this is a very interesting post. However, I think it does the opposite of what I want (changes plot point size independently of the legend). But this is new to me, so I could be wrong. I didn't see any options to change any legend properties though.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518353/how-to-see-the-code-of-a-stored-plot-ggplot

Comment: How exactly are you tying to use `plot_grid`? What doesn't work for you? I'm not sure this question makes the problem very clear. It seems you are stuck on the next step which you are not showing.

Comment: @MrFlick I've edited the question to hopefully make it a little more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is no. A ggplot is like a recipe. The gTree is like the cake that the recipe produces. You can't unbake a cake to get the recipe back.

However, the answer here is that, instead of modifying the legend then extracting it and stitching the plot together, you can stitch the plot together *then* modify the legend. So if you do things in this order:

```r
asdf <- ggplot(exampledata, aes(x = x, y = y, color = z, shape = z)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(color = z, linetype = z2)) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(1, 2, 3)) +
  theme(legend.position = 'top', legend.spacing = unit(2, 'cm'))


b <- ggplot(data = datasetb, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()

prow <- plot_grid(asdf + theme(legend.position="none"),
                  b + theme(legend.position="none"),
                  align = 'vh',
                  labels = c("A", "B"),
                  hjust = -1,
                  nrow = 1)

legend_a <- get_legend(asdf + theme(legend.position = "top"))

plot_grid(legend_a, prow, ncol = 1, rel_heights = c(.2, 1))

grid.ls(grid::grid.force())
grid.gedit("key-1-[-0-9]+-1.2-[-0-9]+-2-[-0-9]+", size = unit(4, "mm"))

# save the modified plot to an object
g2 <- grid::grid.grab()
```

Now we can save (I've had to save as a small png to allow upload here):

```r
png("BothPlots.png", units = 'in', width = 6, height = 3.5, res = 200)

grid::grid.draw(g2)
dev.off()
```

You get:

**BothPlots.png**
[image]

Comment: Very nice, thank you! I ended up skipping the get_legend argument and just produced both plots (each with one half of the entire legend) then stitched together with plot_grid. But this answer works perfectly!